# Base36 encoding and decoding in java

Tags: java, c#, encoding

I'm using C# and Java in my Application. I have windows service which decrypt string using following method:

```
public static String DecryptStringToBase36(String encryptedText, String key)
        {
            if (key == null) key = AesSecretKey;
            encryptedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Base36.Base36StringToByteArray(encryptedText));
            var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(GetRijndaelManaged(key).CreateDecryptor()
                .TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length));
        }
```

But I need to Convert a string say "Hello" in java so that my C# application can decrypt it.
I have tried it using `Base64` in java but it is giving me exception while decrypting in c#.

Comment: So your problem is you need a Base36 implementation in Java? Aren't there any on Google or in Maven?

Comment: The good news is; there isn't a base-36 class built into .NET either; it should be easy to implement / port, though

Comment: out of curiosity: why on earth are you double-encoding everything? you seem to be going: `encryptedBytes <===> base-64 text <===> utf-8 bytes <===> encryptedText=base-36 text` - that is frankly a bit silly; it could just just `encryptedBytes <===> encryptedText=base-36 text` - am I missing something?

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm double encoding because while encryption it produces o/p like 0OlT5wI2D+6079fnEzBmA5hawaFXXZZi5X3LCxjmApsX3LOdtnegnQMufBL8LSGTA7V9ZPAN/hbbez99tIlwSw==
when I call any url with above parameter it creates a problem .that's why I'm double ecoding.
Please suggest good way to encrypt and decrypt so that I can use it over  the web and also whenever required

Comment: I need alphanumeric encrypted value only.

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis that *partly* explains why you are using base-36; it does *not* explain why you are going via 2 additional steps in the middle (each of which adds unnecessary padding); btw - it is also common to simply use base-64 with a slightly different url-safe alphabet (for example, `-` and `_` instead of `+` and `/`) and no padding (no trailing `=`)

Comment: But regards the question: *just port a base-36 converter into java* - that is an hour's work, tops; heck, it could even take 5 minutes;  I'm assuming you have the C# already (since it isn't a .NET standard type) - but [otherwise, this would help](http://www.stum.de/2008/10/20/base36-encoderdecoder-in-c/)

Comment: This is encoding, not encryption.

Comment: @CodesInChaos to be fair, it does at least *touch* on encryption (`GetRijndaelManaged(key).CreateDecryptor()` etc) - the actual *question* is about the encoding aspect though; agreed.